# how to reverse a state in react context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-state

How can i change the state from true to false and false to true?

this is my code :

```
import React, { createContext , useState } from 'react';

export const RegContext = createContext();

const RegContextProvider = (props) => {
    const[mode, setMode] = useState([
        { showing: false }
    ]);

    const changeMode = () => {
        setMode([...mode, { showing: !showing }]);
    };

    return (
        <RegContext.Provider value={{mode, changeMode}}>
            { props.children }
        </RegContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default RegContextProvider;
```

I got this message :

> 'showing' is not defined  no-undef

Can anyone help me resolve this issue??

Comment: why do you have an array holding an object if you want a single prop ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I'm new to js, you can change if that was not correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your `mode` state does is hold a boolean value for showing, you could simplify it to just

```js
const RegContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false);

    const changeMode = () => {
        setShowing(!showing);
    };

    return (
        <RegContext.Provider value={{showing, changeMode}}>
            { props.children }
        </RegContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

---

And to be safer, since the `changeMode` depends on the previous state you should use the callback syntax

```js
const changeMode = () => {
    setShowing((showing)=>!showing);
};
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-darkness-8iscu